# Can we pre populate input.text field in adaptive cards so that when I start typing it will suggest like google?

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I am working on adaptive cards and there's a requirement of adding suggestions in a input.text field of adaptive cards.

Do we have any property in adaptive cards input.text by which we can give suggestions to users as soon as they start typing in textbox.

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: I am using teams channel

Comment: @tdurnford suggest if there's any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this feature is not supported in Adaptive Cards.

If you were using Web Chat, you could use the [attachment middleware](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/10.a.customization-card-components) to modify the cards behavior; however, this functionality is not supported in Microsoft Teams.